# how to make realistic water texture in blender 2.82

Tags: rendering, texturing, color

[image]I am trying to get something vibrant but realistic for some gentle flowing water like if you were pouring it out of a glass on a table.

this is what I got so far but it looks more like paint.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried or what you've got already?

Comment: think blue kool-aid or maybe Windex color and look.

Comment: Might helpful as well: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154467/physically-accurate-water-shader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will look live paint if you are using Eevee. You need to use Cycles. Here is the material that should work(Glass BSDF). Adjust the color to your needs. Also, try adjusting roughness(Lower roughness makes it clearer).

[image]

Comment: thanks this helped and lost protonbender answer help as well thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can make your own transmissive water material and tweak settings,

But i prefer to install an free addon which is included in blender, it's called cycles material library or something like that.

There are many water materials available in it. 
You can find whatever that suits your needs.

You would not need to change anything if you are using cycles but IF YOU ARE USING EEVEE,

1. You will have to turn on screen space refraction
2. You will have to change blend mode to alpha blend from opaque in your water material settings