How to make small waves for a river?
I created a river and created a texture for the water tho i want to create little waves to make it look more realistic. Any suggestion on how i can do so?



You have to plug the Noise Texture into the Height of the Bump node, not the Strength. Afterwards you can adjust the effect by changing the Strength and/or Distance value (the default of 1 is most of the times too high).

Worked perfectly, thank you!

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64/how-can-i-create-a-water-material-in-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154467/physically-accurate-water-shader
